# Why does mounting storage empty other folders

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I tried mounting storage using the new 'Bring your own storage' feature for app services on linux containers and there's some funky stuff happening.

For instance, I have a container running with basically a static site served by `express` in `/home/site/wwwroot`. When I mount storage in `/home/site/wwwroot/assets/config`, the entire `/home/site/wwwroot` folder is empty and the files that sit in the storage account do not appear in `/home/site/wwwroot/assets/config` (that folder is there though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was caused by the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` being set to `true`. I figured this flag was required to enable the 'Bring your own storage' feature. Turns out this flag enables persistence of the container filesystem to Azure Storage in a different way as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/).